# Flow type for React element

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype, flow-typed

This is really document-less about use types in React or React Native.

I found that an element type would be `React$Element<any>` in the [`render()` function](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.48.0/lib/react.js#L230). So I try this in my code:

```js
// @flow
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

function greetingTextNode(string: string): React$Element<any> {
  return (
    <Text>Greeting, { string }.</Text>
  )
}
```

but it shows a flowtype error in console:

```
 20:     <Text>Greeting, { string }.</Text>
         ^^^^^^ Text. This type is incompatible with
 97: type _ReactClass<DefaultProps, Props, Config: $Diff<Props, DefaultProps>, C: React$Component<DefaultProps, Props, any>> = Class<C>;
                                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ React$Component. See lib: /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_243350bf/react.js:97
```

How can I correct the flow type for a react element?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
function greetingTextNode(str: string): React.Element<*> {
  return (
    <Text>Greeting, { str }.</Text>
  )
}
```

You had the correct concept, just not the correct syntax

Comment: Why using `*`, not `any` in the generic type?

Comment: using `*` instructs Flow to infer the type. https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-the-existential-type

Comment: Dear @evanflash, Use `any` instead of `*`